# Adding new lines in HTML

Tags: html

So I'm trying to add text inside a variable and the variable together. But every time I add new text I want it to be added on another line. So when it's spread on multiple lines instead of it being just on one line.

Here is the code I have for it so far. How do I put the old sResults on the lower lines?

```
sResults = ("You Are The Boss" + sResults)
```

I've tried using `<p>` in it but I don't think I'm implementing it right. I tried using `\n` like in AS3 but that's not working and also `<tr>` like for tables but I'm still pretty new to HTML and i have no idea.

Comment: Is this Javascript? Where are the tables? What is the rest of your HTML? I don't understand what you want and how you want it.

Comment: are you using javascript??

Comment: Simple question.. Deserves a [simple answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using javascript then try this way :

```
sResults = ("You Are The Boss" + sResults)
sResult=sResult+"<br>";
```

Comment: Just `<br>`, not `</br>`.

Answer (score 0):

To force a new line in HTML then you need to use the [br tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).